# i do a case when section with group by, after i want a count

Tags: sql, count, case-when

I do the next query:

```
 select case when anum like '0%' then 0 else 1 end anum ,
    ,voucher
    , date 
 from ledger
 group by voucher, date, case when accountnum like '0%' then 0 else 1 end
 order by voucher
```

After that i need a count on anum in one query.

The answer here:
I do the query what i wrote above. Then I get the following result:

```
anum  voucher   date
1     1         2012-09-30
29    1         2012-09-30
2     101       2012-11-01
2     1131_3    2012-01-01
4     1131_11   2012-05-22
4     1131_11   2012-05-22
```

But i want to see this:

```
anum  voucher   transdate
2     1         2012-09-30
1     101       2012-11-01
1     1131_3    2012-01-01
2     1131_11   2012-05-22
```

Comment: *After that i need a count on anum in one query*, I don't understand what this means, can you clarify what it is that you want?

Comment: I do the query what i wrote above. Then I get the following result: anum voucher date
1 1 2012-09-30 00:00:00.000
29 1 2012-09-30 00:00:00.000
2 101 2012-11-01 00:00:00.000
2 1131_0003 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
4 1131_0011 2012-05-22 00:00:00.000
4 1131_0011 2012-05-22 00:00:00.000
But i want to see this: anum voucher transdate
2 1 2012-09-30 00:00:00.000
1 101 2012-11-01 00:00:00.000
1 1131_0003 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
2 1131_0011 2012-05-22 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put it in a subquery:

```
select count(*) as anum, voucher, date
from (
     select case when anum like '0%' then 0 else 1 end anum ,
        ,voucher
        , date 
     from ledger
     group by voucher, date, case when accountnum like '0%' then 0 else 1 end
     order by voucher
) sq
group by voucher, date
```